# Open Local HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried previous questions' answers but it didn't work.

I want to open a local HTML file but it always gives me err file not found.

The HTML code

```
if (result==11111) {
       window.open('file:///NewMask/tpham.html', "_self");}

}
```

And the properties location of the file:

```
C:\Users\Charné\Desktop\MADChallenge\NewMask
```

**Edit:**
Okay I updated it:

```
if (result==11111) {
       window.location="C:\Users\Charné\Desktop\MADChallenge\NewMask\tpham.html";}

}
```

Still gives me ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Why do you not use the full path to the file?

Comment: If it's a local file, just put the actual literal path: `C:\Users\Charné\Desktop\MADChallenge\NewMask\tpham.html`

Comment: How do you want to open it? Why not do `window.location = '/NewMask/tpham.html'`

Comment: Niether ideas work :( (I edited the Original Post)

Comment: Now you have a syntax error with the extra `}` at the end of the line.

Comment: @wlh Why do you need to use `encodeURIComponent()`? That's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Wow! I didn't even notice that, but it is actually part of the rest of the code. Do you think the rest of the code might be the reason the file doesn't want to open?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's part of `window.location = `. And, sure, if you have problems with other parts of your code, it would prevent this from running. What do you see in your Console?

Comment: @ScottMarcus no it worked perfectly before i put this part in. I even tested it with if result==11111 {alert("yes");} and it worked...

Comment: I'm telling you that although your test don't complain: `window.location="C:\Users\Charné\Desktop\MADChallenge\NewMask\tpham.html";}` is an error when followed immediately by another `}`. Your braces don't match up.

Comment: Try `"C:\\Users\\Charné\\Desktop\\MADChallenge\\NewMask\\tpham.html"` with the escape code for a backslash being `\\`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you're a pure genius! It works perfectly x

Comment: For posterity, the escape sequence for a single backslash in JavaScript is `\\\`.